# How do I use two titled borders to surround separate components?

Tags: java, border, panel, title

Hello all I'm currently trying to finish an assignment for school but I'm stuck and there isn't any content on here that can relate directly to my problem. The assignment is to create a GUI application that displays the total for a customer's visit to Joe's. Some of you may know this problem from school. https://bb1ap.tamut.edu/bbcswebdav/pid-281014-dt-content-rid-800291_1/courses/80706_15/week08_activity_25-27.pdf At the bottom of the attached pdf is the problem I'm on and an image of what the finished product should look like. I cannot seem to create the two separate title borders. Any help with this is greatly appreciated. If you can explain it like I'm a 5th grader even better!

```
//Programmer: Davis Bentley
//Date: 10/21/2015
//Purpose: To allow user to calculate auto service cost

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class autoCalc extends JFrame {

private JPanel topPanel;
private JPanel centerPanel;
private JLabel messageLabel1, messageLabel2;
private JTextField autoTextField1, autoTextField2;
private JButton calcButton, exitButton;
private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 450;
private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600;
JCheckBox oil = new JCheckBox("Oil Change ($26.00)");
JCheckBox lube = new JCheckBox("Lube Job ($18.00)");
JCheckBox radiator = new JCheckBox("Radiator FLush($30.00");
JCheckBox trans = new JCheckBox("Transmission FLush ($80.00)");
JCheckBox inspect = new JCheckBox("Inspection ($15.00)");
JCheckBox muffler = new JCheckBox("Muffler Replacement ($100.00)");
JCheckBox tire = new JCheckBox("Tire Rotation ($20.00)");

public autoCalc(){
    super("Joe's Automotive");
    setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    buildPanel();
    setVisible(true);
}
private void buildPanel(){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Joe's Automotive");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(topPanel);
    frame.add(centerPanel);

    topPanel = new JPanel();
    topPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Routine Services"));
    topPanel.add(oil);
    topPanel.add(lube);
    topPanel.add(radiator);
    topPanel.add(trans);
    topPanel.add(inspect);
    topPanel.add(muffler);
    topPanel.add(tire);

    messageLabel1 = new JLabel("Parts charges:");
    autoTextField1 = new JTextField(10);
    messageLabel2 = new JLabel("Hours of Labor:");
    autoTextField2 = new JTextField(10);
    calcButton = new JButton("Calculate");
    calcButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener());
    exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
    exitButton.addActionListener(new exitButtonListener());

    centerPanel = new JPanel();
    centerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Nonroutine Services"));
    centerPanel.add(messageLabel1);
    centerPanel.add(autoTextField1);
    centerPanel.add(messageLabel2);
    centerPanel.add(autoTextField2);
    centerPanel.add(calcButton);
    centerPanel.add(exitButton);
}
private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String input, input2;
        double parts, hours, labor;
        double grandTotal = 0;

        if ( oil.isSelected()){
            grandTotal += 26;
        }
        if ( lube.isSelected()){
            grandTotal += 18;
        }
        if ( radiator.isSelected()){
            grandTotal += 30;
        }
        if ( trans.isSelected()){
            grandTotal += 80;
        }
        if ( inspect.isSelected()){
            grandTotal += 15;
        }
        if ( muffler.isSelected()){
            grandTotal += 100;
        }
        if ( tire.isSelected()){
            grandTotal += 20;
        }
        {
            input = autoTextField1.getText();
            parts = Double.parseDouble(input);
            input2 = autoTextField2.getText();
            hours = Double.parseDouble(input2);
            labor = hours * 20;
            grandTotal += parts + labor;
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total Charges: $" + grandTotal );
    }
}
private class exitButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        dispose();
    }
}

}
```

Heres the code to run it:

```
//Programmer: Davis Bentley
//Date: 10/21/2015
//Purpose: To allow user to calculate auto service cost

public class autoRun {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    autoCalc auto = new autoCalc();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
frame.add(topPanel);
frame.add(centerPanel);
topPanel = new JPanel();
```

A couple of problems:

1. Your topPanel and centerPanel variables are null when you attempt to add them to the frame, so you are actually adding nothing to the frame. Create the panels, add components to the panel and THEN add the panel to the frame.
2. The default layout manager for a JFrame is a BorderLayout. When you add components to the frame and don't specify a constraint, then both compnents are added to the CENTER. However only one component can be displayed in the center.

Try:

```
frame.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
frame.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

and move those statements to the bottom of your `buildPanel()` method.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples.

Keep a link to the tutorial handy for learning Swing basics.

Comment: Those command lines worked, however I had to move them to the constructor and drop the frame part. The only issue I have now is to line up the check boxes all on the left side?

Comment: `Those command lines worked,` - then the answer should be "accepted" by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved. `The only issue I have now is to line up the check boxes all on the left side?` - that is why I gave you the link to the tutorial on layout managers. You need to use a different layout manager (or combination of layout managers) to get your desired layout. Maybe a BoxLayout? Read the tutorial, play with the demos and decide what is best for you.

Comment: Found out how to use a GridLayout. Got the checkboxes lined up now. Thank you very much.